# Spring Security letting any request go through

Tags: spring, security, authentication, header, endpoint

I am making an API with Spring boot + Spring Security. I am having issues with Spring Security "letting" any request go through.

What is happening is that I have two endpoints:

```
users/register/app
users/recoverpasswordbyemail
```

And I am testing them with Postman, the thing is that if I call one of those endpoints for the first time after the app started without an `Authoritation` header or a wrong one, it won't let me in and gives a 401 error. However, If I call the other method or the same method again with a correct `Authoritation` header and then call one of them without the Header again, it'll let me pass. I do not think it's suppossed to work without an auth header.

I am not sure if it is because I have already done some kind of "log in" when I put the correct auth header or if it's a Postman's issue. But I want that every time a call to one of those endpoints a check is done for the user.

**This is my Spring config file:**

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired
 private UserServiceImpl userService;

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
             .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/users/register/app", "/users/recoverpasswordbyemail")
             .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SADMIN")
             .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new NotAuthorizedExceptionMapper())
             .and().sessionManagement().disable();
 }

 @Override
 public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
     builder.userDetailsService(userService);
 }

 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }

}
```

Also every time this happens, the user doesn't get first if exists (however it does when I have a wrong auth header) or whatever as I have in my **UsersService**:

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        User user = userRepository.findById(username).get();

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getRole());
    }
```

This is the URL I use to call the endpoints:

```
http://localhost:8680/ulises/usersserver/users/register/app
```

where `/ulises/usersserver/` is the servlet context

Has anyone a clue of why this can be? I researched quite a lot but saw nothing that could solve it.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that a session was being created despite of sessions being disabled. I don't understand why this is happening but using

`.and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);`

solved my problem.